# Hash table collision in python set?

Tags: python, hash, set, hashtable, hash-collision

How it is possible to have in python set 2 the same elements? Is it the python bug?

```py
type(data_chunks)
<class 'set'>

len(data_chunks)
43130

same = [x for x in data_chunks if x.md5==chunk.md5]
[<Model.Chunk.Chunk o...x0DB40870>, <Model.Chunk.Chunk o...x0DB40870>]

len(same)
2

same[0] is same[1]
True

same[0] == same[1]
True

len(set(same))
1
```

But when I build dictionary from it, duplication is removed!

```
len({k:k.product_id for k in data_chunks})
43129
```

Why it works for dictionary but not for set? I though that it was an collision in hash table, but in fact the duplicated object is *the same object*, so it was not found in a set lookup when next element was added(?)

Additional information:

- `Chunk` has defined `__hash__` and `__eq__` methods
- python 3.7.2
- I've realized that `Chunk` has some properties that throws an error - it shouldn't be important as they are not called
- proceding line of code is:
  `data_chunks = data_chunks | another_set`
- interactive promt during debbuging session in vscode
- when running code it happens *sometimes*
- but during this one debug session creating new sets from data_chunks is always the same lenght

EDIT

Chunk implementation

```py
class Chunk(object):
    def __init__(self,
                 md5,
                 size=None,
                 compressedMd5=None,
                 # ... (more elements)
                 product_id=None):
       self.md5 = md5
       self.product_id = product_id
       # (etc.)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self.compressedMd5:
            return self.compressedMd5 == other.compressedMd5 and self.product_id == other.product_id
        return self.md5 == other.md5 and self.product_id == other.product_id

    def __hash__(self):
        return self.name.__hash__()

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.compressedMd5 if self.compressedMd5 is not None else self.md5
```

==================

EDIT
Ok, so the things in code goes as folows:

`repository` - json descriptor

`chunking_strategy = ...` - mainly class that stores settings, for example that *chunks will be compressed*.

`result_handler = Strategy.DefaultResultHandler(repository)`
Generates unique hashes of chunks objects in repository: chunks and corresponding files mapping. **Later it will call compression jobs and then set compressedMd5 and other properties of existing chunks.**

```
generation_strategy = Strategy.CachingGenerationStrategy(
            result_handler,
            Settings().extra_io_threads,
        )
```

`data_chunks = Strategy.DepotChunker(repository, chunking_strategy, generation_strategy)()`

on DeputChunker init: todo chunking jobs are prepared based on chunking_strategy settings. Then `generation_strategy.__call__` method process all jobs: files to be chopped into small chunks based on previously defined Chunk objects. This is done in `multiprocessing.Pool`. After physical chunks are created they md5 is checked and Chunk object are *updated* with `compressedMd5`, `compressedSize` and `product_id`.
Then (just **after changing Chunk object**) chunk objects are added to set.
This set is return from `DepotChunker`

Then compressed chunks are saved in cache.

---

Then all data_chunks are search for small objects with small size, from which physical chunks (in memory buffer) are created that consist of merged small files. Let us call them smallFilesChunks. They are added to `data_chunks`:

```
     sfChunk = Chunk(
                sfCompressedContentMD5,  # yes I see that this is compressed md5 - it was intended for some reason I don't know
                size=sfSize,
                compressedMd5=sfCompressedContentMD5,
                compressedSize=sfCompressedSize,
                product_id=productId
            )
        if not sfChunk in data_chunks:  # purly sanity check
            data_chunks.add(sfcChunk)
```

---

At the end meta files are created and they are also chunked and added to `data_chunks`

Then meta files are dumps, and they are chunked as well.

```
for depot in manifest_depots:
        data_chunks = data_chunks | simpleChunker(depot)
```

At this point debugger session from the begining was recorded

Comment: Probably need to see the implementation of `Chunk` too to identify any issues with hashing

Comment: Yes, let's see the hash function and the comparison methods.

Comment: Also, is `Chunk` mutable?

Comment: @Mesco please edit your post to include a proper minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: It seems that `__hash__` is using the  `__hash__` method on either `compressedMd5` or `md5` - do they implement `__hash__` the same way? You are constructing the list `same` based on equality of only the `md5` attribute, whereas `__hash__` is and `__eq__` are checking other attributes as well.

Comment: md5 is string. CompressedMd5 is Optional[str,  None]

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I wish to do so...I'm trying to solve strange bugs in our application that occurs *sometimes* even on the same machine with just another try

Comment: @Chris_Rands see: len(data_chunks) and len({k:k.product_id for k in data_chunks}) results

Answer (score 4):

One problem is that `__eq__` is not commutative for pairs of objects where one has `compressedMd5` and the other does not (i.e. its `compressedMd5` is set to `None`). This means that it's possible to construct two objects `a` and `b` such that `a == b` and simultaneously `b != a`.

A related problem is that `__eq__` and `__hash__` are not consistent with each other in similar circumstances (`__eq__` would refuse to look at `other.compressedMd5` if `self.compressedMd5` is `None`.)

Mutability can also be a problem, as illustrated by the following example:

```
class Chunk(object):
  def __init__(self, md5):
    self.md5 = md5

  def __hash__(self):
    return hash(self.md5)

s = set()
chunk = Chunk('42')
s.add(chunk)
chunk.md5 = '123'
s.add(chunk)
print(s)
```

On my computer, this produces `set([<__main__.Chunk object at 0x106d03390>, <__main__.Chunk object at 0x106d03390>])`, i.e. the same object appears in the set twice.

Something similar could be happening in your code if you change `md5` or set/unset/change `compressedMd5`.

Comment: Thanks, I see the problem. But currently `len([x for x in data_chunks if x.compressedMd5 is None]) == 0` and in fact - `same` arrays consists of two the same elements `object at 0x0DB40870`

Comment: @Mesco: Are `Chunk` objects mutable?

Comment: I I understand the difference - no, its not. But looks like it is not change anywhere beside creation time

Comment: In fact, md5 and compressedMd5 are properties, and actual class values are dunders (i've simplified paste code)

Comment: @Mesco: It's really hard to debug a subtle issue like this by proxy/guesswork. :(

Comment: Which operations did you perform on the chunk between adding it first and adding it again? It looks like some operations can change the hash, that's most likely the issue.

Comment: But wouldn't we then expect `len(set(same))` -> `2`? Also AFAIK `set` and `dict` use a hashtable to construct keys, so I'm not sure why `set(data_chunks)` has dupes and `{k:k.product_id for k in data_chunks}` does not. If I had to guess I'd say I agree with NPE that `__eq__` and `__hash__` are not performing the same comparisons here, but it's odd all around. There's something we don't know about the operations on `Chunks` here.

Comment: I've set debugger in every Chunk setter. I'll update question for more details. @Hans-MartinMosner looks like preparing more chunks from cache and then adding to main chunks set. But will check deeper (this will took some time, as one chunking session lasts about 1h in this case)

Comment: @Jeff exactly! I know that mutability issues counts... but how it is possible to do in a breakpoint when everything is let say it "freezed"?  That 1) `set(same)` has no duplicates but `set(data_chunks)` has 2) dict build from `data_chunks` is smaller

Comment: @Mesco: To me, those symptom strongly hint at the mutability of `Chunk` (in particular, that a chunk's hash changes during the chunk's lifetime).

Comment: @Mesco: While we're exploring the various ways in which things might go wrong, is there any concurrency in any of part of this code?

Comment: @NPE There are more thread used for generating chunks, and then uploading to server. After chunks are physically generated based on Chunk objects, they are compressed. Then Chunks objects are updated with compressMd5. Then chunks are added to `data_chunks` set. (see my update for more details)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I understand that this is the kind of behaviours that are difficult to reproduce reliably so all we can come with ATM are suggestions on what could possibly cause such issues...

In addition to  what NPE already mentioned, you do have a potential issue with `Chunk` being mutable: both the `md5` and `compressedMd5` attributes can be changed at anytime, so the result of `hash(chunk)` is not garanteed to be stable. You may want to check your codebase for eventual gremlins here. If you find any code updating one of those attributes *after* a `chunk` has been added to the set, then you probably have the culprit. FWIW remember that Python never implicitely copies anything so something like this:

```
chunks = set()

def make_chunk(md5, ...)
   c = Chunk(md5, ...)
   chunks.add(c)
   return c

def do_something_bad(chunk):
    chunk.md5 = something_else

def main():
   c = make_chunk()
   # ... lots of code here
   do_something_bad(c)
```

WILL reflect the change in `chunks` and mess up eveything (nb: yes, you very probably already know that, but that's a very common pitfall for peoples coming from more mainstream languages)

NB : that's only an issue if anything changes one of those attributes of course, but making them read-only would still be safer (well, at least according to Python's definitions of "read-only" and "safe" that is xD).